# docker-compose command not running on `up`, but on entering container command runs

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file as such:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  my_service:
   ...
   command: /bin/bash my_script.sh
   ...
```

and a script that launches some [`rq workers`](https://python-rq.org/docs/workers/) in the background:

```sh
# my_script.sh
rq worker worker_1 &
rq worker worker_2 &
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build -d`, the `my_service` image is built and creates a container, but `my_script.sh` does not run.

If instead I change the `docker-compose.yml` file to:

```yaml
   ...
   command: tail -f /dev/null
   ...
```

run `docker-compose up --build -d` again, enter the container with:

```sh
# host
$ docker exec -it my_service_1 /bin/bash
```

and run the same command from within the container

```sh
# my_service_1 container
$ /bin/bash my_script.sh
```

then `my_script.sh` runs successfully. I have checked file paths are fine, and there is no `ENTRYPOINT` associated with the `Dockerfile` for `my_service`. I have also checked the container logs with `docker logs my_service_1`, but this does not return any output.

Has anyone encountered anything similar before? Why am I unable to run `command: /bin/bash my_script.sh` directly from the `up` command?

Kindly let me know if there is anything I should clarify in more detail, or avenues for debugging this. Thank you.

Comment: What is the image you are running; can you provide its Dockerfile?  Does the image use `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD`?  (Why do you need to explicitly name the `bash` interpreter to run your script?)

Comment: Why don't you move the "command" to inside the Dockerfile instead of the docker-compose file?

Comment: @DavidMaze I neither use `ENTRYPOINT` nor `CMD` in the Dockerfile (hence using `command` in the compose file). I  name `bash` since using the default interpreter was throwing other errors.

Comment: @everspader - yes i suppose i could, but isn't the point of having `command` in `docker-compose.yml` , is to remove this duplicity?

Comment: I think of it as an option, either in the docker-compose or the Dockerfile. Typically I prefere to let the Dockerfiles handle the CMD/ENTRYPOINT of the container.

Comment: Launching background processes in a container can lead to some subtle difficulties.  Does the script do anything other than start background processes?  Can you refactor this to run multiple containers, with one foreground process each?